# Why does the Unanswered button take me to a list of questions with answers?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Why does the Unanswered button take me to a list of questions with answers?

Shouldn't I got to a list of questions with no answers, perhaps with the oldest one first?

If the are questions whose answers have no up votes then shouldn't there be a different button for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unanswered means that either the answers don't have enough upvotes to be considered a good answer, or the person that asked the question has not selected an answer as the accepted answer.

Like the first question on the list, [How to set a text theme for plymouth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122830/how-to-set-a-text-theme-for-plymouth) the answer has no upvotes, and the user commented that that was not what what he was looking for, so it still does not have an "answer".

If you want to find questions that no one has tried to answer try this custom search:

https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=closed%3a0%20answers%3a0%20votes%3a0&page=1

Here is one sorted by the oldest first:

https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=oldest&q=closed%3a0%20answers%3a0%20votes%3a0